# JPA + Hibernate: how to use array bind with CriteriaBuilder, i.e., make final query be like "... in (?)", not "... in (?, ?, ?)"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using CriteriaBuilder of JPA to build a long IN clause. Then, I found that Oracle does not support > 1000 elements in IN clause, so I need to divide this clause into several, like `in (?, ?, ?...) or in (?, ?, ?)`.

This is done, but I think we need to optimize more, as variable length of param list cannot be optimized at DB side: due to the length is changing, Oracle optimizer will think each one is a different query, so the execution plan will change. But I think they are basically one, or two queries, as this IN clause is possible, but seldom contains > 1000 elements. So, if I can bind the list to one variable, it will be 99% of the time `in (?)`, and 1% of `in (?) or in (?)`, which is very good for Oracle to see the similarity.

I found Hibernate has a `setParameterList()` like said [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)), and I think this is what I need. And I know I can `unwrap()` a JPA `Query` into a Hibernate `Query`, like:

```
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString()
```

so I want to do the same to use the method of `setParameterList()`. But Hibernate complains about "named parameter not found".

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [excluded_orgIds0]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameterList(AbstractQueryImpl.java:839)
    ....
```

What do I do now?

EDIT:
I found that `setParameterList()` is already called in the implementation class, and it can map my named param to Hibernate positional param, but seems like Hibernate will convert a list to string at last, so the array binding is not possible.

`org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.class`:

```java
    public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(String name, Object value) {
        try {
            if ( value instanceof Collection ) {
                query.setParameterList( name, (Collection) value );
            }
            else {
                query.setParameter( name, value );
            }
            registerParameterBinding( getParameter( name ), value );
            return this;
        }
        catch (QueryParameterException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( e );
        }
        catch (HibernateException he) {
            throw getEntityManager().convert( he );
        }
    }
```

Why?

---

One possibility:
The whole SQL is like:

```
select ih from ItemHistory as ih where ( ih.code=:param0 ) and ( ih.companyId in (select c.id from Company as c where ( ( c.organizationId in (:param1) ) or ( c.organizationId like :param2 ) or ( c.organizationId like :param3 ) ) and ( ( ( c.organizationId not in (:param4) ) and ( c.organizationId not in (:param5) ) ) and ( c.organizationId not like :param6 ) )) ) order by ih.eventDate desc
```

When I set `code` or `eventDate` or `not like ...`, I don't use parameter, but just put in the values (`queryBuilder.eq(column, "333")`). I only use `queryBuilder.parameter(List.class, param1)` where there is a IN clause.

Do positional param has precedence, so that if I want to use parameters, I need to use them in all the places?

Comment: You cannot bind the list to one variabel. This is not supported by JDBC and the database

Comment: That also count as an answer, good. So anyway, a list will be converted to several params in string, and for DB, they will be different queries, so optimizer cannot kick in, right? These structurally identical queries but with varying numbers of params in IN clause will be a pain for Oracle(and other DBs), right?

Comment: Exactly! May I ask why you have these large number of IN parameters?

Comment: I don't quite understand why, as they don't come from DB. I can try to find out why, maybe Monday.

Comment: Maybe they are from user auth service, another microservice. If that is true, I don't have access to that DB.

Comment: .. which is legit: in modern schema of organizations by micro services, one service handles user info and passes the user principal to another service, which has access to user schema; and each other services does whatever they want with this principal object, fetching from db again, maybe from another schema. But, we may see this kind of problem. @SimonMartinelli Doubt what better solution we could have..